# How can I inject a dependency into a Spring Modules Validation (Valang) custom function?

Tags: java, spring

I want to inject a dependency into a custom spring modules validation function. I have tried using @Autowired on the setter, but it has no effect. Does anyone know if or how this can be done?

Here is my valang validator:

```
<bean id="resellerValidator" class="org.springmodules.validation.valang.ValangValidator">
    <property name="customFunctions">
      <map>
        <entry key="isValidResellerId" value="com.myproject.valang.IsValidResellerIdFunction" />
      </map>
    </property>
    <property name="valang">
        <value>
        <![CDATA[
            {resellerId: ? IS BLANK OR isValidResellerId(?) IS TRUE : '' : 'field.badFormat'}
        ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And here is the custom function:

```
public class IsValidResellerIdFunction extends AbstractFunction {

    private ResellerService resellerService;

    @Autowired
    public void setResellerService(ResellerService resellerService) {
        this.resellerService = resellerService;
    }

    public IsValidResellerIdFunction(Function[] arguments, int line, int column) {
        super(arguments, line, column);
        definedExactNumberOfArguments(1);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doGetResult(Object o) throws Exception {
        String resellerId = (String) getArguments()[0].getResult(o);
        return resellerService.isValidResellerId(resellerId);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually wound up finding the answer [here](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/spring-modules-validation-module.html). In summary, 2 things were needed:

1. Create a FunctionWrapper bean and inject my custom function into the wrapper with scope="prototype". This allows me to inject any dependency I want into my custom function.
2. Implement the ConfigurableFunction interface so it works with FunctionWrapper.

The FunctionWrapper is automatically discoverable by all valang validators, so no need to declare the custom function explicitly with the customFunction property, and the name of the function is just the bean name you give the FunctionWrapper:

```
<bean id="resellerValidator" class="org.springmodules.validation.valang.ValangValidator">
    <property name="valang">
        <value>
        <![CDATA[
            {resellerId: ? IS BLANK OR isValidResellerId(?) IS TRUE : '' : 'field.badFormat'}
        ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="isValidResellerId"
      class="org.springmodules.validation.valang.functions.FunctionWrapper"
      scope="prototype">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
    <property name="function">
        <bean id="isValidResellerIdFunction"
              class="com.myproject.valang.IsValidResellerIdFunction"
              scope="prototype">
            <property name="resellerService" ref="resellerService"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The function:

```
public class IsValidResellerIdFunction extends AbstractFunction implements ConfigurableFunction {

    private ResellerService resellerService;

    public void setResellerService(ResellerService resellerService) {
        this.resellerService = resellerService;
    }

    public IsValidResellerIdFunction() {}

    @Override
    public int getExpectedNumberOfArguments() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void setArguments(int expectedNumberOfArguments, Function[] arguments,
            int line, int column) {
        super.setTemplate(line, column);
        super.setArguments(arguments);
        super.definedExactNumberOfArguments(expectedNumberOfArguments);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doGetResult(Object o) throws Exception {
        String resellerId = (String) getArguments()[0].getResult(o);
        return resellerService.isValidResellerId(resellerId);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your application context:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this had no effect.